Does a random variable that includes the summation of independent samples from different distributions obey Central Limit Theorem?

I am learning from the book of statistics by sheldon M ross and it's a great book. However, I landed upon a small query that book failed to address me. According to CLT , sum of random variables when n is sufficiently large is normal regardless of the underlying distribution of the individual random variables. Now My question is do these individual random variables necessarily have to have identical(same) distributions for the central limit theroem to hold.Let's say that I pick certain samples from one distribution say normal, another one from exponential and few other from binomial and add them provided them they are independent,their sum is still obeying normal  distribution or not?
It's like X= X1+X2+X3+......+Xn
where X1,X2,X3 are from normal distribution
X4,X5,X6 from binomial distribution
X7,X8, .. from exponential distribution and so on .
What I simply meant was that these random variables are coming from different distribution not identical. Will there sum also be normal?
I tried to simulate using python code and found it turned out to be normal .Is it ok to generalize this outcome or too naive?
  import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Parameters
lam = 2  # Lambda parameter for exponential distribution



list1=[]
for i in range(10000):
  normal_samples = np.random.normal(4,9,5)
  exponential_samples = np.random.exponential(scale=1/lam, size=3)
  binomial_samples = np.random.binomial(100, 0.1, 3)

  sum_exponential=np.sum(exponential_samples)
  sum_random=np.sum(normal_samples)
  sum_binomial=np.sum(binomial_samples) 

  # Calculate the sum of random variables
  sum_X = np.sum(sum_exponential+sum_random+sum_binomial)
  list1.append(sum_X)

  # Plot histogram
  
plt.hist(list1, bins=100, density=True, alpha=0.6, color='g')
print(list1)


plt.show()



For more about this, search our site (or elsewhere) about the Lindeberg condition.
